# TDSRestConnection firedac reflextion and Login exceptions

Tags: authentication, delphi, exception

I have a development with firedac reflections in D10.3.3
I'm using my own form for user login.
The problem arises when the login fails or the session expires.

It is understood where I must capture these exceptions as to notify the user and close the application or call the Login form.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How to fix the issue.
First perform exception capture at the application level. In the main form, I capture all the exceptions.
On the other hand, I made a singleton of a datamodule with only the connection to the database. This allows me to use the same connection and store the user's login.

I hope this scheme will help someone.

If anyone has any other suggestions, they will be welcome.